# Error when tring to execute apoc.refactor.mergeNodes

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have neo4j version server 3.5.18 and I've installed apoc version 3.5.0.11. I think that I have correctly modified the conf file in this way

```
dbms.directories.plugins=/Users/lx2pwnd/Desktop/dev/neo4j-community-3.5.18/plugins
...
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=algo.*,apoc.*
...
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
```

But when I try to execute a query which contains `CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(..)` i get this error:

```
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `plugins` path needs to be relative to the neo4j installation directory. This is safer, since different neo4j versions can be installed simultaneously, and they may need different plugin versions.

Try changing the `dbms.directories.plugins` value back to `plugins`, putting the APOC jar file in the existing `plugins` directory under your neo4j installation directory, and restarting neo4j.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, I've correct the path, but the error was in `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*`. I modified it in `dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*` and now it works